# How to hook into civiDiscount code

Tags: contributions, contribution-page

I'm trying to set up a system where when a member joins, they can add another member at a reduced rate.  I want the second member to log in and sign up, checking a box for a release for.  I thought the easiest way to do this would to give a discount code of 100% for the second member and the first member would pay for both.  I know I could create a new discount code for each member but I'd rather not fill up the database with one time discounts, so I would like to hook into the code  that the Apply button uses to examine the code entered and then change the amounts if it passes muster.  I thought I could just use hook_civicrm_preProcess and change the amount on the form but this doesn't work.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Is this just when the first member is signing up (2-for-1 deal), or do you want the first member to be able to add a second member later?

Comment: Just the first member.  He creates a membership for himself and pays for another one for which he is given the discount code.